# Oracle SQL | Efficiently counting Clicks grouped by Week as well as all sub-totals

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a large and slow database 'LargeSlowTable' which records clicks by users. I only have read permission, not write, so I cannot use `Global Temporary Tables`. I want to count the number of clicks, grouped by week. I also want to count the distinct/unique number of clicks. The following code does this nicely. (*There is a reason I have the second `Select` nested inside the first `Select`.*)

```
SELECT Week, COUNT(Click), COUNT(DISTINCT Click) FROM
(
SELECT
Week,
Click
FROM LargeSlowTable
WHERE Id = 2
)
GROUP BY Week
ORDER BY Week;
```

Now, I also want a count of the total number of unique clicks, from the starting date to the present. This is not simply the sum of all unique clicks per week, as those may shows clicks by the same user. Therefore, I need to run another command which ignores the `GROUP BY Week` part.

Can I do this without calling the LargeSlowTable again?

Finally, I would also like a sub-total per week of the number of unique clicks, from the starting date to that particular week.

Can I do this without calling the LargeSlowTable again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to identify first user click, then count only rn=1 with `decode` or `case when` for these new, additional columns:

```
select week, cc, cdc, sum(cda) over() "all distinct clicks", 
       sum(cda) over (order by week) "distinct clicks to that week"
  from (
    select week, count(click) cc, count(distinct click) cdc, count(decode(rn, 1, 1)) cda
      from (
        select lt.*, row_number() over (partition by click order by week) rn 
          from largeslowtable lt where id = 2)
      group by week)
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74ef8/1)</sup>

Comment: Wow! Awesome :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports analytic functions, so you can use:

```
SELECT Week, COUNT(Click), COUNT(DISTINCT Click),
       MAX(CumeDistinctClicks)
FROM (SELECT Week, Click,
             COUNT(DISTINCT click) OVER (ORDER BY Week) as CumeDistinctClicks
      FROM LargeSlowTable
      WHERE Id = 2
     ) lst
GROUP BY Week
ORDER BY Week;
```

There is overhead to analytic functions, so this will probably not be as fast as your original query.

EDIT:

That's odd, I really thought that Oracle did support `count(distinct)` in window functions.  An alternative method uses two aggregations:

```
SELECT Week, SUM(cnt), COUNT(DISTINCT Click),
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CumeDistinctClicks
FROM (SELECT week, click, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY click ORDER BY week) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT Week, Click
            FROM LargeSlowTable
            WHERE Id = 2
           ) lst
      GROUP BY click, week
     ) cw
GROUP BY Week
ORDER BY Week;
```

Comment: Thank, but:
ORA-30487: ORDER BY not allowed here
30487. 00000 -  "ORDER BY not allowed here"
*Cause:    DISTINCT functions and RATIO_TO_REPORT cannot have an ORDER BY
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 68